# How to unzip a zip file to a folder but avoid duplicate folders?

Tags: windows, 7-zip

I think you all know that: you're getting a zip file and you don't know whether it contains all files in a folder or only the files. In order to not get a messed up directory, I never use `"Extract here"` but always use `"Extract to <Foldername>"` (using 7Zip).

Unfortunately, if the Zip file has a folder, there are always two folders, so I need to move the files up one directory level.

Is there a way to always extract into a folder but avoid duplicate folders like `\ZipFileName\FolderInZip\`?

***Update***

I'm looking for context menu operations of ZIP files, not opening the ZIP file first. Speed is everything :-)

Comment: Asked again three years later, [on software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28104/an-intelligent-unzipping-program-for-windows). The answer here is good, and (currently) also accepted there;  future readers might want also want to read that one for completeness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is *exactly* [Bandizip](https://www.bandisoft.com/bandizip/) by Bandisoft.

In Bandizip's settings, select the `Context Menu` heading.  Then, under `Extraction Menu`, enable `Extract Automatically`.

If you like, you can even enable the `Extract Automatically` functionality as the default double-click action by selecting `Extract Automatically` in the `Double-click Action` section of that same settings page.

When you use Bandizip's `Extract Automatically` functionality, it will create a subfolder only when one is needed.  If the zip file only contains a single file or subfolder, it will *not* create a subfolder.  If the zip file contains a bunch of files, it will automatically create a new subfolder for you.

Enjoy!

[image]

*Image source: bandisoft.com*

Answer (score 2):

When you open a zip archive in 7-Zip, the GUI will have a column called Folders.  If all items contain a value in the Folders column, you don't have to unzip to a new separate folder.

Comment: That's true, but requires even more clicks to first open the archive, click Extract, select the destination folder, press Ok and close 7Zip. Maybe I should mention that I extract via context menu only.